# Cómo hacer el envío de JSON por POST mediante POSTMAN, web service PHP, Apache

Tags: php, json, apache, post, xampp

Buenas Noches,

Estoy intentando hacer pruebas a un web service en PHP desde POSTMAN enviando un JSON, pero mis intentos son sin éxito,
1-Intente cambiando la url de http a htpps
2- Cambie de $_REQUEST a $_POST
3- Configure el postman para que en HEADER fuera application/JSON.

Mi código PHP

```
<?php
$conexion= new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=anna","root","");

$correo = $_POST['correo'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$res=$conexion->query("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE correo = '$correo' AND password = '$password'");

$response = array();
$response["success"] = false;  

foreach($res as $row){
    $response["id_usuario"] = $row["id_usuario"];
    $response["success"] = true;  
    $response["nombre"] = $row["nombre"];
    $response["apellido"] = $row["apellido"];
    $response["correo"] = $row["correo"];
    $response["telefono"] = $row["telefono"];
    $response["password"] = $row["password"];
    $response["id_rol"] = $row["id_rol"];
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>'; ?>
```

Mi JSON

```
{
"correo":"elisa.y3@gmail.com",
"password":"2"}
```

Por último las imagenes de la respuesta en POSTMAN

[Respuesta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cJQQ.png)

[image: Respuesta 2]

[image: Respuesta 3]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias por la colaboración.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los valores se envían en el cuerpo de la solicitud, en el formato especificado por el tipo de contenido.

Por lo general, el tipo de contenido es `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, por lo que el cuerpo de la solicitud utiliza el mismo formato que la cadena de consulta:

```
parameter=value&also=another
```

Traducido de : [Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551194/how-are-parameters-sent-in-an-http-post-request)

Te anexo una imagen quizas es lo que querias lograr:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me sirve de esa forma, sin embargo aún no me queda muy claro porque no puedo hacer uso del servicio enviando el json raw

Answer (score 0):

Saludos!

Después de leer varias explicaciones en internet me dí cuenta que el error estaba en cómo intentaba capturar las variables correo y password.

1- Debía decodificar el JSON
2- Obtener los valores de correo y password de esa misma decodificación.

Anexo el código y el cómo realice la prueba desde POSTMAN

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$conexion= new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=anna","root","");
$response = array();

$body = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);

$correo = $body['correo'];
$password = $body['password'];

$res=$conexion->query("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE correo = '$correo' AND password = '$password'");

    if ($res->rowCount() <1){
        $response["success"] = false; 
        $response["codigo_mensaje"] = "999999";
        $response["mensaje"] = "USUARIO O CLAVE ERRADA";

    }else{
        foreach($res as $row){
            $response["id_usuario"] = $row["id_usuario"];
            $response["success"] = true;  
            $response["nombre"] = $row["nombre"];
            $response["apellido"] = $row["apellido"];
            $response["correo"] = $row["correo"];
            $response["telefono"] = $row["telefono"];
            $response["password"] = $row["password"];
            $response["id_rol"] = $row["id_rol"];
            $response["codigo_mensaje"] = "000000";
            $response["mensaje"] = "OPERACIÓN EXITOSA";
        }
    }
echo json_encode($response);
```

?>

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]